# QuTip newbie need to understand .reshape()

Tags: qutip, programming

I am a quantum physics researcher but till now I have been using Mathematica symbolic language for solving quantum problems. I wanted to develop numerical skills as well so I just started to learn QuTip. I am ok at Python and need help occasionally with some concepts. So here is where I am stuck right now:

```
def sim_transform(old1, old2, new1, new2): 
#Form the similarity transform from one basis to another.
# Calculate the relevant inner products:
a = new1.dag()*old1 
b = new1.dag()*old2 
c = new2.dag()*old1 
d = new2.dag()*old2 

# extract values from these Qobj inner # product results, reshape to 2 by 2, and # form a new Qobj matrix: 
s = [i.data[0,0] for i in [a,b,c,d]]
return Qobj(array(s).reshape(2,2))
```

In the above function, can someone please explain to me what do last two lines do? I don't understand what data, i.data, array(s).reshape(2,2) do.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression

```
s = [i.data[0,0] for i in [a,b,c,d]]
```

is a standard Python loop comprehension iterating over the set `[a, b, c, d]` (which represent the variables (arrays?) above). It appears to generate a list containing the elements `[0,0]` from each of the arrays `a, b, c, d`.

I suspect that the `reshape` is modelled after numpy's reshape ([link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)). In the example, a $1 \times 4$ vector is being converted to a $2 \times 2$ matrix:
$$
  [ a, b, c, d ] \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} $$